# XmlSerializer namespace is not visible, why?

Tags: .net, xml-namespaces, xmlserializer

I have class which I want to serialize:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FileInfoMessage")]
public class Message : IMessage
{
 [XmlAttribute]
 public int Id { get; set; }

 [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "Files")]
 public Version { get; set; }
 //...
}
```

and my serialize method:

```
//_xmlData - string containing xml content
public void SerializeData(IMessage message, Encoding encoding)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = encoding, OmitXmlDeclaration = false, Indent = true, NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.Default };
                var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, writerSettings);
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(message.GetType());
                var namespaces = new  XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                namespaces.Add("", "Files"); //if I add custom prefix, it will be visible
                serializer.Serialize(writer, message, namespaces);
                stream.Position = 0;
                _xmlData = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            }
```

what I want to achive is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<FileInfoMessage Id = "1" **xmlns="Files"** Version="2">
 //...
</FileInfoMessage>
```

but I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<FileInfoMessage Id = "1" p1:Version="2" xmlns:p1="Files">
 //...
</FileInfoMessage>
```

and if I change in my SerilizeMethod line:
namespaces.Add("whateverIwant", "Files");

i got:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
    <FileInfoMessage Id = "1" **xmlns:whateverIwant="Files"** Version="2">
     //...
    </FileInfoMessage>
```

any possible way to make it happen?

*Post edited after few changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an empty string for the first parameter to namespaces.Add("", "Files). As far as I can remember this does the trick.

Comment: you mean namespace.Add(string.Empty, "Files"); ?

Comment: It's the same thing. Either "" or String.Empty.